# how to store reference of 2d array in a 1d array in java?

Tags: java, arrays, multidimensional-array

I have a collection of 2d arrays for representing graph. i want to store this collection in a array so that each element of that 1d array points to corresponding 2D array.M using java

Comment: Can you show some example code? What does your 2D array look like?

Comment: for representing graph m using adjancency matrix .

Answer (score 0):

Make use of Jagged arrays.
See the link below:
http://way2java.com/arrays/jagged-arrays-varying-column-size-arrays/

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `toArray` method of `Collection` :

```
// Primitive type arrays:
Collection<int[][]> intArrayCollection = null;
int intArray[][][] = intArrayCollection.toArray(new int[0][][]);

// Reference type arrays (String, for example)
Collection<String[][]> stringArrayCollection = null;
String stringArray[][][] = stringArrayCollection.toArray(new String[0][][]);
```